# Bloom filter when n > m

Tags: algorithm, bloom-filter

```
n = # of items
m = # of bits in BF array
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Optimal_number_of_hash_functions) says the optimal number of hash functions is `k = (m/n) ln 2`.

What if `n` is much greater than `m`?  For example, if we have a huge amount of items but only a limited amount of memory for the bloom filter.  If `m` was 1 million, then using the `k` formula, `n` being 10 million or 10 billion would both result in `k` defaulting to 1 hash function.  I would think that `k` would increase along with `n`, to better distribute the items and minimize the number of false positives.

Comment: If all the bits are set in the bloom filter, then it doesn't do any filtering.  The more hash functions per item, the more bits that are set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I mistakenly thought that `n` was the length of the BF, instead of the number of bits set.  What if we started with a clean BF, of limited length (i.e. memory), and we knew we had relatively much more items that will be added to the BF.  Could we calculate `k` at the start?

Comment: Or is `k` supposed to change as we add items and bits are set (I'm new to bloom filters).

Comment: `k` won't change when items are added, because how are you supposed to retroactively apply new hash functions to the existing items?

Comment: @jsheeran I see.  BFs seem like they aren't a great fit when `n > m`.  Since `k` will default to 1, and `n - m` items will collide regardless if they're duplicate.  We could do additional rounds of filtering until `n <= m`, but that would be `n/m` rounds, with total time complexity `n/(2m)*(n+m)`.